# Console app or web api for scatter gatherer recipients?

Tags: c#, rest, rabbitmq, integration

I am trying to learn more about the scatter gatherer pattern.  Say I have the following recipients:

```
1) Offer1
2) Offer2
3) Offer3
```

These offers will receive messages from RabbitMQ and publish replies to RabbitMQ.  Therefore there will be no Web API endpoints.

I am debating whether these should be console applications or web api projects.  I believe they should be web api projects because there are no web api endpoints e.g. GET; PUT etc.

Is there any reason they should be web api projects? The reason I ask is because the examples I have looked at online appear to be web api projects and I cannot see a reason for this, so I wander if I am missing something.

Comment: There is no reason to use a web api if you don't want to expose an api. However, if you want to put the messages from remote systems, identity management is a lot easier with a web endpoint involved. If you only use this internally, there is no need for an api.

Comment: @Jesse de Wit, I guess I would use consoles for offers hosted internally and web apis for offers hosted externally.  Is that what you mean?>

Comment: My point is any application CAN place messages on RabbitMQ, but if you have untrusted clients putting messages, it would probably be a good idea to wrap that in a web api, for more fine-grained access management.